# Paired sample: Two-tailed and one-tailed

Tags: t-test, paired-data, one-tailed-test

In the book: "Essentials of Statistics for Business & Economics", the part about matched sample t-test, I see that it uses the two-tailed t-stat. However, instead of stating the null and alternate hypotheses as "equal 0" and "not equal 0", it sets: "H0 d <= 0" and "H1: d > 0", which seems like a one-tailed test. I'm wondering whether this is correct?

Comment: Why do you want to include < 0 as part of the null hypothesis?

Comment: It sounds like you're correct and the book has an error.

Comment: That's certainly a one-tailed test as the hypotheses are stated.

Answer (score 0):

Then the book has a mistake. A two-sided t-test has $H_0: d = 0$ and $H_a: d \ne0$.

(I assume that $d = \mu_1 - \mu_2$ or $d = \mu_2 - \mu_1$.)